# Eliminate mesh / grid lines in python pcolor basemap plot

Tags: python

I'm using Basemap and pcolor to plot a scalar field on a cylindrical projection. The problem I'm having is that the grid lines are drawn: I don't want to see the lines, just the coloured squares. If I wanted grid lines, I would use pcolormesh, right?

The help says that setting edgecolors='none' should eliminate the lines (the same thing as the now-deprecated shading='flat'). In my case, for the real data I'm trying to plot, it doesn't seem to do so.

In did a test where I coloured a little square right over the top of a part of my map: I just made a new 3x3 random array and some suitable lat/lon matrices. In that little test patch the lines between the individual colours are not visible (what I want); I just don't know why, I used the same technique for that as for the real data.

The unwanted grid is black because the map background is black `map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='0.05')`, where 'map' is a Basemap object:

```
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',
              resolution='l', 
              llcrnrlon=lon_min, 
              llcrnrlat=lat_min, 
              urcrnrlon=lon_max,
              urcrnrlat=lat_max)
```

When I leave the background white, I see a white grid instead of black.

The pcolor command I use is:

```
mymapim = map.pcolor(mapxvals, mapyvals, datafield, edgecolors='none', vmin=-5, vmax=35, cmap=my_cmap)
```

'datafield' is a masked array (not sure whether masking might have something to do with it). 'map*vals' are matrices which have one more row and column than datafield.

So I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and trying to find an answer on the web, but I think I'll take this opportunity to ask this community my first question. Thanks for any suggestions. (I haven't been using python for long).

I tried to attach an image showing the issue but I can't until I get some reputation apparently.

Ta!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether I have fully understood your question. [Here](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/users/examples.html) are some examples on how to use `pcolor`, `imshow` and `contour` in `Basemap`.

Comment: Thanks imsc, I had seen those examples, they're neat.

I think imshow would be what I would like to use (much faster than pcolor), but I couldn't figure out how to make it work on a map projection where I had an irregularly-spaced grid. Contour isn't suitable for my purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately `imshow` will only work for regular-spaced grid. If you want faster plots, try setting `rasterized=True` in `pcolor`. You can gain speed at the cost of quality of the image.